# Is there a document creator that allows for basic entry?

Tags: math-software

I am really not sure how to word this...

I'm wondering whether there is a program that allows for document writing, and works in a similar way to the Equation Editor in MS Word? (obviously without having to add equations ever time)

I'm completely new to LaTeX and all that - (don't worry, its on the list to learn) - but I need to write a large assignment with plenty of formulas...so if there's something out there that has this functionality, that would be great!

Cheers,

Jack

Comment: LaTeX is probably your best bet (I know you referenced it but it shouldn't take too long to learn). Here's a quick tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference If you have further questions, please direct them to the tex.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is LaTeX, which you mentioned. A nearly no-knowledge direct entry might be to use [sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/).

You might ask if there is an alternative - and the answer is *no*, because $\TeX$ is extremely good.

Comment: Wow, I like that site. What would you recommend in desktop packages? (Windows) Cheers.

Comment: The desktop thing to use is just real LaTeX. You sound like a Windows user, so you might check out http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/how-do-i-install-tex-latex-on-windows-7 ([tex.se] also has good instructions for many TeX needs - it's not as hard as it might seem at first)

Comment: It's not just that it's good. It's also superior to anything else when done right.